# ERROR: 'Spec 'ChromeLauncher works' has no expectations.'

Tags: angular, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I had written test cases for my angular component. In total there are 11 test cases that I need to execute. The test cases are running fine but I am getting this error every time apart from my 11 test cases that I had executed.

The error is :

```
Chrome 66.0.3359 (Windows 10 0.0.0) ERROR
  {
    "message": "An error was thrown in afterAll\n[object ErrorEvent]\n[object ErrorEvent]\n[object ErrorEvent]\n[object ErrorEvent]",
    "str": "An error was thrown in afterAll\n[object ErrorEvent]\n[object ErrorEvent]\n[object ErrorEvent]\n[object ErrorEvent]"
Chrome 66.0.3359 (Windows 10 0.0.0): Executed 12 of 12 ERROR (0.45 secs / 0.413 secs)
```

The Chrome console is like this :

```
12 specs, 0 failures, randomized with seed 84434Error during loading: [object ErrorEvent]Error during loading: [object ErrorEvent]Error during loading: [object ErrorEvent]Error during loading: [object ErrorEvent]

    Component : Filter Component
        should create
        selectFilterValue should be called after setInitialFilterValues
        setInitialFilterValues should be called on reset
        ngOnint called, setInitialFilterValues should be called


    ChromeLauncher
        SPEC HAS NO EXPECTATIONS works

    testService : Service
        if data is valid then return sum of key
        if data is undefined return undefined
        if data is not empty return success
        if data is empty return undefined
        if data is empty then return sum of key
        test week number of given date
        test first date of the week
```

I have only 11 test cases to run and they are executing fine but, here on chrome console 12 specs are being executed due to which  I am not getting a clean output on console.

How can I fix this?

EDIT:

karma.conf.js

```
module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular/cli'],
    files: [
      {pattern: '../assets-ts/tests/src/*.spec.ts', included: false},
      {pattern: '**/*.spec.js', included: true}
    ],

    plugins: [
      require('karma-jasmine'),
      require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
      require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
      require('karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter'),
      require('@angular/cli/plugins/karma')
    ],
    client:{
      clearContext: false // leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser
    },
    coverageIstanbulReporter: {
      reports: [ 'html', 'lcovonly' ],
      fixWebpackSourcePaths: true
    },
    angularCli: {
      environment: 'dev'
    },
    reporters: ['progress', 'kjhtml'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['Chrome'],
    singleRun: false
  });
};
```

tsconfig.spec.ts

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/spec",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es5",
    "types": [
      "jasmine",
      "node"
    ]
  },
  "files": [
    "test.ts"
  ],
  "include": [
    "../tests/**/*.spec.ts",
    "**/*.spec.ts",
    "**/*.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Could you please post your karma configuration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing the following section from karma.conf

```
`files: [
  {pattern: '../assets-ts/tests/src/*.spec.ts', included: false},
  {pattern: '**/*.spec.js', included: true}
],`
```